# how to create custom control in visual studio 2015 and add it to toolbox

Tags: c#, dll

I want to create a control that draw a table in class library project .and add this dll to toolbox and use it in my windows form app. I try and googling but I can't find. 
what should i do ?

I created this class in class library project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
class PanelZ : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    private Color color1 = Color.SteelBlue;
    private Color color2 = Color.DarkBlue;
    private int color1Transparent = 150;
    private int color2Transparent = 150;
    private int angle = 90;

    public Color StartColor
    {
        get { return color1; }
        set { color1 = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Color EndColor
    {
        get { return color2; }
        set { color2 = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int Transparent1
    {
        get { return color1Transparent; }
        set
        {
            color1Transparent = value;
            if (color1Transparent > 255)
            {
                color1Transparent = 255;
                Invalidate();
            }
            else
                Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int Transparent2
    {
        get { return color2Transparent; }
        set
        {
            color2Transparent = value;
            if (color2Transparent > 255)
            {
                color2Transparent = 255;
                Invalidate();
            }
            else
                Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int GradientAngle
    {
        get { return angle; }
        set { angle = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public PanelZ()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(color1Transparent, color1);
        Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(color2Transparent, color2);
        Brush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, c1, c2, angle);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

but when i add mydll to toolbox i get this error 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVS0e.png)

Answer (score 2):

In WPF or Winforms the Toolbox is smart about components that are part of the solution you are building.  For Winforms, simply add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` to your class library and then inherit from `Control` (or any other class that inherits from `Control`).

For example, I can create a custom control like this (Note that it has to be a public control for the toolbox to find it):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class CustomControl : Control
    {
        public CustomControl()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Once I build the project, I can then see it in the Toolbox when interacting with my Form in my application.

[image]

Comment: can i create it in class library project and add this dll to toolbox ?

Comment: If they are in separate solutions, then you can add it to the toolbox by using the right click menu in the toolbox, selecting `Choose Items` and browsing to your DLL.

Comment: I updated the answer to indicate the cause of your error.  It needs to be a `public` control